# C# Weird division issue

Tags: c#, math

I have one int and one uint type:

```
int tempA = 0xbc000669;
uint tempB = 0xbc000669;
```

when I do

`tempA /0x2000`, wanting to shift to the right by 13, it gives me `0xfffde001`

while

`tempB / 0x2000`, wanting also to shift to the right by 13, it gives me the correct answer: `0x0005e000`

anybody knows why with a signed division, I get a false answer? I didn't think division could overflow? Thanks

Comment: What version of C# do you use? Most probably this code just doesn't compile - it wants first to convert `0xbc000669` to int, but then it says that "Constant value '3154118249' cannot be converted to a 'int' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)". Anyway - it's just because in signed version original value is below zero. So result is too below zero

Comment: `-1140849047 / 8192` should indeed be `-139263`. There's no error here.

Comment: Division of a signed integers by a power of 2 is equivalent to an arithmetic right shift, whereas division of an unsigned integer by a power of 2 is equivalent logical right shift.  That's why the results are different.

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé only almost - a signed division rounds negative results towards zero, whereas an arithmetic right shift rounds downwards.

Comment: @harold Agreed. I just didn't want to complicate things by bringing rounding rules into to play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the statement

```
tempA / 0x2000
```

the compiler sees a variable of type int and a numeric literal value. Since division on type int requires two operands of type int, the value 0x2000 is automatically cast to int as well. The statement evaluates to

```
(int)0xbc000669 / (int)0x2000
```

which is
-1140849047 / 8192 and equals to -139263

-139263 in hex is FFFDE001 (on 32 bit values at least)

Answer (score 1):

`0xbc000669` in fact **can't be contained** in an `int`, more exactly it will represent a `negative integer`. We know that an `int` uses the `32nd bit` as the `sign bit`. While `0cbc000669` has the most significant nibble as `0xb` which is equal to `1011` -> the `32nd bit` is `1` and the actual integer is negative. So:

```
int tempA = 0xbc000669;
```

will make `tempA` equal to `-1140849047`, right-shifting this number 13 binary digits will return the exact result you get: `0xfffde001`.

if you declare your `tempB` as `uint` like this:

```
uint tempB = 0xbc000669;
```

it can be contained totally in a `uint` because `uint` doesn't use the `32nd bit` as the sign bit. The actual number is a `positive integer` and its value is `3154118249`, right-shifting this value 13 binary digits will give you the exact result as `0x5e000`

Answer (score 0):

From the blurb in the spec about integer division:

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the absolute value of the quotient of the two operands. The result is zero or positive when the two operands have the same sign and zero or negative when the two operands have opposite signs.

If I interpret that text correctly, it leads to this: In the first example, the signed int value has the sign bit set; the second number (0x2000) is positive, thus the result is either zero or negative.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to explain this is to show how the bits work out.  [The Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) article on signed number representation covers it well.  You'll want to read the the section on Two's complement.

The expectation, I think, is that people want the binary of -1 and 1 to be the same, with the exception that the sign bit is 1 for -1.  This is not the case.  1, for example, is

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

And -1 is

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

What people would intuitively think is -1 is actually -127:

```
-127 == 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

So now let's look at the the answers you got.  In signed division, when you shift to the right, you actually end up padding the left side of your number with 1s, and adding 1.  And that's exactly what you see with your results.

```
0xFFFDE001 = 1111 1111 1111 1101 1110 0000 0000 0001
0x0005E000 = 0000 0000 0000 0101 1110 0000 0000 0000
```

As you'll notice, they're both the same, except the top one(from your signed division) has 13 1's padded on the left, and an added 1 at the end.

The important thing to remember with signed integers is that two's complement changes the ordering of bits, so, excluding the sign bit, -50 does not have the same bit pattern as +50.